# Remove git history for distributing project for bug report?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, commit, bug-reporting

My iOS app is having a strange core data bug, and I contacted Apple's developer technical support for help. They are asking me to submit a copy of the offending code, so they can see what is going on exactly and help me identify the problem, but as one would expect I don't want to give them all my code, not only because it is proprietary but also because I want them to be able to identify the arts of the code that are having issues.

So I have removed 95% pf my code so that the app still builds and loads, and the problem can be demonstrated. I would like to provide them with a git repository, so that the developer who looks at my code can see how the changes I am making creates the bug.

However, I don't want to send them the whole git repository as it stands because the history would allow them to just go back in time, and undo all of the deleting work that I did. What is the proper way to go about "pruning" a copy of my git repository, so that a particular commit will become the root of the new commit tree?

Comment: Why do you feel the need to provide any history at all? If you've got a minimal program that demonstrates the bug, then you've given them all they need to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete a given file/files using git filter-branch.

See here:
https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html

Specifically, you may use the following example to delete a file named as filename:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch filename' HEAD
```